# Filter orders using a WP_Query from an array of orders IDs in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I got an array of orders ID's and `'post__in' => $orders_ids` to embed them in a `WP_Query`:

```
$filters_orders = array(
    'post_status' => 'processing',
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__in' => $orders_ids,
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($filters_orders);
while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $order = new WC_Order($loop->post->ID);

    <HERE_MY_CUSTOM_HTML_TABLE>
}
```

I am filtering "processing" order status only, but it doesn't work and I get all kind of status.

What I am doing wrong? How to filter order status correctly in this WP_Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `WP_Query`, you need to use the `post_status` slugs like in the database table `wp_posts`… All orders status start with "`wc-`":

So in your case: **`'post_status' => 'wc-processing'`**.

This should work now.

Comment: Oh Damn.. I checked the code many times.. Ok thanks @LoicTheAztec !